# Check if EditText Number Decimal is Empty

Tags: android, android-edittext

I tried everything.

```
if (editText == null)...

if (etNumero1.getText().toString().isEmpty())...

if (etNumero1.getText().toString().equals("")...

if (etNumero1.getText().toString().trim().length() >= 0))
```

Nothing works. Even my teatcher cant tell whats wrong.
Sorry for bad english im Brazilian.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add details to your question as we could really understand what you try to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Check, If the value is not an Empty**

```
if (!etNumero1.getText().toString().isEmpty())
{
  if(etNumero1.getText().toString().contains("."))
  {
    //Do your functionality here
  }
}
else
{
  //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (Integer.parseInt(etNumero1.getText().toString()) > 0)
```

If you specify your question, I could answer in better condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use TextUtils.isEmpty("") check for null if not convert to formart to ###.##

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not making mistake on editText  etNumero1??
I know editText is Edit Text but what is etNumero1?? please replace etNumero1 to editText, it should work

```
if (editText.getText().toString().isEmpty())...
```

Example:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText editText =  findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Button button = findViewById( R.id.button );
    button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            if(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("empty string");
            }else{
                System.out.println("" + editText.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: etNumero1 is the id of my edit text. I tried your example and it doesnt work. I wish i could send images.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(String.valueOf(editText.getText() != null){
    Double double = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString);
}
```